# How can I make doctrine not persist duplicate objects in my database?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, deduplication

I have two different kinds of objects: **Ride** and **Location**.

A **Ride** has an *origin* and a *destination* which are **Location** objects.

**Location** does not point back to the **Ride**.

This means I have a many-to-one uni-directional relationship in doctrine.

How can I make doctrine ensure that I don't have any duplicate **Location** objects in my database?

For Example:
If I create a **Ride** from Minneapolis, MN to Mankato, MN and persist them I now have stored one **Ride** and two **Location** objects in my database.

Now that those are persisted, I go to create another **Ride** from Mankato, MN to New Ulm, MN and persist them.

Doctrine has duplicated the **Location** Mankato, MN.

Does doctrine have this functionality, or is it my responsibility to check if I am creating duplicate objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you put a unique constraint on Location Name (Maybe state name + city name)?

It's your responsibility to see if the location already exists. And if so, fetch it and supply it to your Ride object.

```
class Ride {
   private $from;
   private $to;

   public function setFrom(Location $from) {$this->from = $from;}

   public function setTo(Location $to) {$this->to = $to;}
 }
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I thought. Thanks for the input!